# How to use getConstructor with Generic class?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

This is my first brush with reflection and generics in Java so please pardon my ignorance. I am trying to instantiate a class using reflection and generics but getting error in my toy program. The goal is to instantiate with constructor of inst class.

Code:

```
/*
*This is the builder class to build an instance
*/
package generics.expClassT;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class builder {
    public static<E> E createInst(Class<E> c) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        //Class<?>[] type = new Class<?>[1];
        //type[0] = inst.class;
        try {
            Constructor<E> ctor = c.getConstructor(c); //c.getConstructor(type);
            return (ctor.newInstance("Testing"));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}


/*
* This is the class for which we need an instance
*/
package generics.expClassT;
public class inst {
private String var;
public inst(String s) { 
    this.var = s;
}
public String getVar() {
    return var;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    inst instObj;
    try {
        instObj = builder.createInst(inst.class);
        System.out.println(instObj.getVar());
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: generics.expClassT.inst.<init>(generics.expClassT.inst)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2800)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1708)
at generics.expClassT.builder.createInst(builder.java:15)
at generics.expClassT.inst.main(inst.java:19)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at generics.expClassT.inst.main(inst.java:20)
```

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `getConstructor(String.class)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Constructor<E> ctor = c.getConstructor(c);` should be `Constructor<E> ctor = c.getConstructor(String.class);`

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...))

> Returns a Constructor object that reflects the specified public constructor of the class represented by this Class object. The
>   **parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects that identify
>   the constructor's formal parameter types, in declared order**. If this
>   Class object represents an inner class declared in a non-static
>   context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing
>   instance as the first parameter.
>   The constructor to reflect is the public constructor of the class represented by this Class object whose formal parameter types match
>   those specified by parameterTypes.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   parameterTypes - the parameter array

This, basically, means, that `getConstructor(Class...)` expects you to pass the class types that have been defined by the classes constructor, in your case `public Inst(String s)`

#### Builder

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Builder {

    public static <E> E createInst(Class<E> c) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        //Class<?>[] type = new Class<?>[1];
        //type[0] = inst.class;
        try {
            Constructor<E> ctor = c.getConstructor(String.class); //c.getConstructor(type);
            return (ctor.newInstance("Testing"));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

#### Inst

```
public class Inst {

    private String var;

    public Inst(String s) {
        this.var = s;
    }

    public String getVar() {
        return var;
    }
}
```

#### Main

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inst instObj;
        try {
            instObj = Builder.createInst(Inst.class);
            System.out.println(instObj.getVar());
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Hi Thanks for such a fast response! I am trying to call the constructor of inst class so shouldn't I pass the object of inst? Please advise.

Comment: Why?  `getConstructor` clearly states that it expects the "formal parameters" of the class.  This will then find the constructor which is defined within the class as matching those parameters and returns it.  The only constructor you have is `public Inst(String s)`, so you should be passing `String.class` to the `getConstructor` method...

Comment: Think of it like "Please get me the constructor for my Class<Inst>, which has the parameters of `String`"...

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much for setting me straight, I missed the most important statement from your answer.

"The parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects that identify the constructor's formal parameter types, in declared order"

Comment: Since I am a new member so I can't vote your answer but I sure give you a thumbs up! Thanks!